# VBA Permutate 1D array adding set value to each array item n number of times

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to figure out a loop logic to get all possible permutations where I add a set value to each item in a set array iLoop number of times. I'm gonna try my best to explain what I am looking for.

I have a set value "StrokeValue" and a set array "DistanceMatesArray"

```
Dim StrokeValue as single
Dim DistanceMatesArray as variant

StrokeValue = 300
DistanceMatesArray = Array(300, 300, 300, 300)
```

Now I need to loop through each possible result where I add StrokeValue to each Item which in the first loop would result in possible DistanceMatesArrays:

[image]

The tricky part is when I want to add StrokeValue more than once and get every outcome where I added StrokeValue iLoop number of time "AllowedActions" resulting in a list such as:

[image]

I kind of suspect that I need a 2D array to store all the results from previous loop., that's why in the example the rows are coloured to indicate which one row was taken as a starting point to add the StrokeValue once

What I got so far looks like this:

```
Public StrokeValue As Single
Public DistanceMatesArray As Variant
Public iError As Long
Public NumberOfCombinations As Long
Public x As Long
Public y As Long
Public i As Long

Option Explicit

Sub Test()

'Declare variables
Dim PreviousLoopResultsArray As Variant
Dim NextLoopResultsArray As Variant
Dim iresults As Long
Dim iLoop As Long
Dim iPreviousResult As Long

'Set variables
StrokeValue = 300

'Array
DistanceMatesArray = Array(300, 300, 300, 300)
ReDim NextLoopResultsArray(0, UBound(DistanceMatesArray))

For i = LBound(DistanceMatesArray) To UBound(DistanceMatesArray)
    NextLoopResultsArray(0, i) = DistanceMatesArray(i)
Next i
'------------------------------------------------------
'Loop
Do While iError = NumberOfCombinations
    
    'Try DistanceMatesArray
        For i = 0 To iresults
            For x = 0 To UBound(DistanceMatesArray) 'Loop horizontally
                DistanceMatesArray(x) = NextLoopResultsArray(i, x)
            Next x
            Debug.Print Join(DistanceMatesArray)
            'TRY HERE
        Next i
    
    'Array
    PreviousLoopResultsArray = NextLoopResultsArray
    
    'Array
    If iLoop <> 0 Then
        For x = 0 To UBound(DistanceMatesArray) 'Loop horizontally
            DistanceMatesArray(x) = PreviousLoopResultsArray(iPreviousResult, x)
        Next x
    End If
    
    'Set variables
    iLoop = iLoop + 1
    iPreviousResult = 1
    iresults = ((UBound(DistanceMatesArray) + 1) ^ iLoop) - 1
    ReDim NextLoopResultsArray(iresults, UBound(DistanceMatesArray))
    
    'Populate NextLoopResultsArray
    For y = 0 To iresults 'Loop vertically
        
        If y Mod (UBound(DistanceMatesArray) + 1) = 0 And y <> iresults And y <> 0 Then
            For x = 0 To UBound(DistanceMatesArray) 'Loop horizontally
                DistanceMatesArray(x) = PreviousLoopResultsArray(iPreviousResult, x)
            Next x
            iPreviousResult = iPreviousResult + 1
        End If
        
        For x = 0 To UBound(DistanceMatesArray) 'Loop horizontally
            NextLoopResultsArray(y, x) = DistanceMatesArray(x)
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(y + 1, x + 1)
                .Value = NextLoopResultsArray(y, x)
            End With
        Next x
    Next y
    
    'Modify NextLoopResultsArray
    x = 0
    For y = 0 To iresults 'Loop vertically
        NextLoopResultsArray(y, x) = NextLoopResultsArray(y, x) + StrokeValue
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(y + 1, x + 1)
            .Value = NextLoopResultsArray(y, x)
            .Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End With
                
        If x + 1 > UBound(DistanceMatesArray) Then
            x = 0
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next y
    
    'Set variables
    iPreviousResult = 0
    
    'Excel reset
    For i = 1 To (UBound(DistanceMatesArray) + 1)
        Columns(i).Clear
    Next i
Loop

End Sub
```

At the end of the loop I am expecting to have each one row as DistanceMatesArray i.e. one of them would now be

```
DistanceMatesArray  = array(300,600,600,300)
```

Where it added StrokeValue twice.

Would someone, please, help me figure out a shorter and simpler logic behind this?

EDIT:

Results expected after running it up to 3 loops looks like this:
[image]

And without duplicate outcomes

[image]

Continuing to try and figure out the logic of it, maybe now someone get's a betetr idea for what I am lookign for and can help

No need to mention that it's an infinite loop - I know that and That's the point, it needs to go on untill I validate the right array in which case iError <> NumberOfCombinations.

Comment: Is the point that the prevention of duplicates is included in said code?

Comment: Nop, the point is to revise the logic I have used to something that's more of how it is when explained in words because in my solution it's extremely hard to explain what is what and how it returns the values making it hard to return to the code and to make any changes taking in account two temporary arrays I am using to store results of the next and previous loops.

Comment: Looking for a logic to permutate DistanceMatesArray right away using the explained logic. The results without duplicates is just there, if someone thinks or knows of a solution that prevents them - they'll have a reference dataset. I.e. InitialDistanceMatesArray and PermutatedDistanceMatesArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been able to learn more about arrays, so I consider this a big win.
The code took in account the duplicates but for now your iterations are hardset (could easily ask how many iterations with an inputbox), not in the endless loop you had set up, hope that rework won't be too much.
Some variables are reworked, I tried to keep most of your original ones though.

```
Public StrokeValue As Single
Public DistanceMatesArray As Variant
Public iError As Long
Public iTerations As Long
Public i As Long
Public j As Long
Public k As Long

Option Explicit

Sub TestArrayfill()

    Dim pArray As Variant, nArray As Variant, cArray As Variant 'pArray = previous array, nArray = next array, cArray = check array
    Dim iresults As Long, iLoop As Long, nb As Long, actB As Long, addCounter As Long, Lastrow As Long
    
    'Set variables
    StrokeValue = 300
    addCounter = 1
    iTerations = 4
    
    'Array
    DistanceMatesArray = Array(300, 300, 300, 300)
    nb = UBound(DistanceMatesArray) + 1
    ReDim Preserve DistanceMatesArray(1 To nb)
    cArray = DistanceMatesArray
    ReDim pArray(1 To nb, 1 To nb)
    
    For i = 1 To nb
        pArray(1, i) = DistanceMatesArray(i)
    Next i
    actB = nb
    
    For iLoop = 1 To iTerations 'I can't figure out the limitations with permutations so we'll just bruteforce it with nb*actB (maximum possibilities)
        ReDim nArray(1 To nb * actB, 1 To nb) '(re)setting nArray
        If iLoop = 1 Then actB = 1 'workaround to have pArray as a 2D-array
        For i = 1 To actB 'loop through every row in pArray except for when iLoop = 1
            For j = 1 To nb 'loop through every cell in pArray(i)
                For k = 1 To nb 'setting the extra StrokeValue
                    If j = k Then
                        cArray(k) = pArray(i, k) + StrokeValue
                    Else
                        cArray(k) = pArray(i, k)
                    End If
                Next k
                If Not arrElemInArray(cArray, nArray) Then
                    For k = 1 To nb
                        nArray(addCounter, k) = cArray(k) 'add the "row" to our nArray
                    Next k
                    addCounter = addCounter + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        actB = addCounter - 1
        ReDim pArray(1 To actB, 1 To nb) 'ReDim is possible on both dimensions, Redim Preserve is not so we use this to our advantage
        For i = 1 To actB 'another loop is necessary however
            For j = 1 To nb
                pArray(i, j) = nArray(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
'        nArray = Application.Transpose(nArray)
'        ReDim Preserve nArray(1 To nb, 1 To actB)
'        nArray = Application.Transpose(nArray)
'        pArray = Application.Transpose(pArray)
'        ReDim pArray(1 To UBound(nArray, 2), UBound(nArray, 1))
'        pArray = Application.Transpose(pArray)
'        pArray = nArray
        addCounter = 1
        Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Lastrow = 1 Then
            Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value = "Loop" & iLoop
        Else
            Cells(Lastrow + 1, 1).Value = "Loop " & iLoop
            Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
        End If
        Cells(Lastrow + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(nArray, 1), UBound(nArray, 2)) = nArray
    Next iLoop
    
End Sub

Function arrElemInArray(arr As Variant, arrX As Variant) As Boolean 'this is from one of your previous questions btw, just a bit modified to fit our needs
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolFound As Boolean, mtch

   If Not IsArray(arrX) Then
         For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j) = arrX Then arrElemInArray = True: Exit For
        Next j
        Exit Function
   End If
   For i = LBound(arrX) To UBound(arrX)
        boolFound = True 'True at beginning so if any cells deviates from the corresponding check, it gets set to False, ergo it doesn't exist yet.
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j) <> arrX(i, j) Then
                boolFound = False
            End If
        Next j
        If boolFound Then arrElemInArray = True: Exit Function
   Next i
   arrElemInArray = False
End Function
```

Hope it's all clear and works for you :)

Comment: Oh wow, however first of all taht's teh whole thing that teh loop is potentially infinite and is stopped only by me checking the result. there's infinite number of actions to be taken i.e. say You wanna buy an item and you don't know the price of it but you start with 1$ and then check if that's enough, if not - you perform an action (add 1$) and try again and so on infinitelly - you could reach 1k $ till you find that it's finally enough. Each loop represents the number of actions you are able to take

Comment: In my case I can't know the result before time because the actual result permutation array is what is affecting and permutating the correct outcome which is not the point the OP

Comment: That's why it needs to brute force each combination possible taking one more "action" for each big loop :).  That's why in my version of this code it keeps on looping till the number of errors is less than possibilities meaning that there was at least one valid outcome and I take that result :)

Comment: So I was kinda thinking if there's a logic behind iterating, say whenperforming said action it loops through DistaceMatesArray, say You wanna perfomr a loop (number of elements in distancematesarray) times but each next starting point is offsetted by one, or something, So in this case you go 0, 1,2,3,0 and then add strokevalue and then you offset starting point to "1" and do that and once the whole 4 permutations are completed, you now wanna loop to 0 and start from 1 but keep the previous loops result to make it so taht you've added teh strokevalue twice

Comment: There must be a mathematical logic behind this is all I'm saying to avoid saving resultarrays of previous and next loop

Comment: Your code seems to also do the task :) however it's insanely hard to understand when variables aren't named using full words :D

Comment: Oh and I can't use excel functions in this, it's for use in a different API

Comment: Ok... that's a lot to take in. Making the iterations bigger shouldn't be an issue. Getting out of an infinite loop would require a check-out fail-safe however but unless you explain how you saw that going, it's difficult to implement in my code. 
As for your next comment about the 0,1,2,3,0 iterations, I don't know exactly what you meant with that. However, you're right, a lot of these type of coding issues can be resolved better with a proper mathematical solution. I'm sadly not your man for this :c 
Lastly, I'll check about leaving the excel functions out tomorrow with extra array.

Comment: Got rid of the transposes, I hope that's what you meant with excel functions.

Comment: That's what I meant, yup

Answer (score 1):

I understood your logic for the first table
but for the following ones I find it difficult to understand what you want especially in relation to the capture that you put in your message

for the first

```
Sub testing()
Dim StrokeValue As Single
Dim DistanceMatesArray As Variant
Dim i As Long 'variable  row iteration
Dim c As Long 'variable column itération
Dim Table As Variant 'variable  variant no dimention in the first

StrokeValue = 300

DistanceMatesArray = Array(300, 300, 300, 300)    'is an array in base 0

nb = UBound(DistanceMatesArray) + 1    'convert a ubound of DistanceMatesArray in count (in base 1)

ReDim Table(1 To nb, 1 To nb)    'table dimensioning (variant) in base 1

'loop for row
For i = 1 To UBound(Table) 'start at index 1
    
    'loop for column
    For c = 1 To UBound(Table, 2) 'start at index 1
        
        'if index row and index column then item has multipled by (2)
        If c <> i Then Table(i, c) = StrokeValue Else Table(i, c) = StrokeValue + StrokeValue
    
    Next c

Next i

'just for see on sheet
Cells.Resize(UBound(Table), UBound(Table)) = Table
```

End Sub

Comment: TYSM for giving an answer. Yeah it's a tricky logic to wrap ones head around. Maybe it's easier to imagine the values in the DistanceMatesArray as distances between bricks that are placed in a line on some kind of a template that has holes in it. Initially I am setting those distances and seeing if every brick falls into a hole in the template

Comment: If that doesn't happen I wanna move the first brick once by the amount of StrokeValue which cases all the next bricks to maintain the distance to this first one, right? And then check if all the bricks fall in to the holes. If not I now wanna move the previous brick back to where it was and move the second one the amount of StrokeValue resulting in all the next bricks maintaining their distances. This is our first loop with 4 possible DistanceMatesArray results

Comment: Now if none of them worked, I wanna separately move the bricks twice now where the first result would be move the first brick twice and check if that is a valid result. If not - Move the first and the second one separately by the amount of StrokeValue resulting in a "600,600,300,300" and so on. It's kind of like spacing the bricks out until I find the combination that fits the template

Comment: And I am guessing that for each next loop of adding the StrokeValue I wanna save all the previous loop results so that I go through each one adding StrokeValue to each item in it before moving to the next initial DistanceMatesArray, you know?